# Use PhantomJS to extract html and text

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, phantomjs

I try to extract all the text content of a page (because it doesn't work with Simpledomparser)

I try to modify this simple example from the manual

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementById('myagent').textContent;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

I try to change

```
return document.getElementById('myagent').textContent;
```

to

```
return document.textContent;
```

This doesn't work.

What's the right way to do this simple thing?

Answer (score 4):

This version of your script should return the entire contents of the page:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://www.httpuseragent.org', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var ua = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;
        });
        console.log(ua);
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to retrieve the page content as a string:

- `page.content` gives the complete source including the markup (`<html>`) and doctype (`<!DOCTYPE html>`),
- `document.documentElement.outerHTML` (via `page.evaluate`) gives the complete source including the markup (`<html>`), but without doctype,
- `document.documentElement.textContent` (via `page.evaluate`) gives the cumulative text content of the complete document including inline CSS & JavaScript, but without markup,
- `document.documentElement.innerText` (via `page.evaluate`) gives the cumulative text content of the complete document excluding inline CSS & JavaScript and without markup.

`document.documentElement` can be exchanged by an element or query of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the text content of the page, you can try this`return document.body.textContent;` but I'm not sure the result will be usable.

Comment: Hi I try it but but it resturns NULL

Answer (score 0):

Having encountered this question while trying to solve a similar problem, I ended up adapting a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865849/phantomjs-javascript-read-a-local-file-line-by-line) like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file_h = fs.open('header.html', 'r');
var line = file_h.readLine();
var header = "";

while(!file_h.atEnd()) {

    line = file_h.readLine(); 
    header += line;

}
console.log(header);

file_h.close();
phantom.exit();
```

This gave me a string with the read-in HTML file that was sufficient for my purposes, and hopefully may help others who came across this.

The question seemed ambiguous (was it the entire content of the file required, or just the "text" aka Strings?) so this is one possible solution.

Comment: You don't need to use the streaming API for simply reading a file. Just use `var header = fs.read('header.html')`.