# Access raw "page.content" from phantom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I am using the [`phantom`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) module with Node.js not the [`phantomjs`](http://phantomjs.org/) runtime.

How do I access [`page.content`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html)?

The example below does not work.

```
var phantom = require('phantom')

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {
      console.log(status) // -> success
      console.log(page.content) // -> undefined
      console.log(page.getContent()) // -> undefined
      ph.exit()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. the code above doesn't work logs undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the phantom module (bridge between node.js and PhantomJS) is asynchronous in nature, the API is a little different from plain PhantomJS. The differences are described on the project page, particularly in the [Functional Details](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#functionality-details):

> Properties can't be get/set directly, instead use `page.get('version', callback)` or `page.set('viewportSize', {width:640,height:480})`, etc. Nested objects can be accessed by including dots in keys, such as `page.set('settings.loadImages', false)`

In your case that would be

```
page.get("content", function(content){
    console.log(content);
});
```

This should give you the complete DOM. See my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27796290) for different ways of getting different representations of the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

```
var phantom = require('phantom')

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {
      if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access the network!')
      } else {
        page.evaluate(function () {
          return document.body
        }, function (body) {
          console.log(body)
          ph.exit()
        })
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: This doesn't access the full page content just the body object.