# Parse BeautifulSoup element into Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

I want to get the source code of a website using selenium; find a particular element using BeautifulSoup; and then parse it back into selenium as a selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement object.
Like so:

```
driver.get("www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.source)
element = soup.find(title="Search")

element = Selenium.webelement(element)
element.click()
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8):

A general solution that worked for me is to compute [the xpath of the bs4 element](https://gist.github.com/ergoithz/6cf043e3fdedd1b94fcf), then use that to find the element in selenium,

```
xpath = xpath_soup(soup_element)
selenium_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
```

...

```
import itertools

def xpath_soup(element):
    """
    Generate xpath of soup element
    :param element: bs4 text or node
    :return: xpath as string
    """
    components = []
    child = element if element.name else element.parent
    for parent in child.parents:
        """
        @type parent: bs4.element.Tag
        """
        previous = itertools.islice(parent.children, 0, parent.contents.index(child))
        xpath_tag = child.name
        xpath_index = sum(1 for i in previous if i.name == xpath_tag) + 1
        components.append(xpath_tag if xpath_index == 1 else '%s[%d]' % (xpath_tag, xpath_index))
        child = parent
    components.reverse()
    return '/%s' % '/'.join(components)
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks

Comment: This is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
search_soup_element = soup.find(title="Search")
input_element = soup.select('input.gsfi.lst-d-f')[0]

search_box = driver.find_element(by='name', value=input_element.attrs['name'])
search_box.send_keys('Hello World!')
search_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

This pretty much works. I can see reason for working with both webdriver and BeautifulSoup but not necessarily for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to pass from bs4 to selenium but you can just use selenium to find the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@title="Search"]').click()
```

Or to find using just the title text like your bs4 find:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Search"]').click()
```