# read local file in phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm attempting to write a script which is able to take a screenshot given an url using phantom.js. This works great when I supply the url(s). However, I would like to be able to read urls from a file in much the same way as in:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865849/phantomjs-javascript-read-a-local-file-line-by-line) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19939046/phantomjs-fails-to-open-local-file). However, all methods return with

> unable to open file 'filename.txt'

Am I missing something here?
Working from a win7 installation.

EDIT:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file_h = fs.open('urls.txt', 'r');
var line = file_h.readLine();

while(line) {
console.log(line);
line = file_h.readLine(); 
}

file_h.close();
```

The output I get is:

```
unable to open file 'urls.txt'
phantomjs://platform/fs.js:79 in open
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the whole filepath? `c:/dira/dib/.../filename.txt`? Also make sure the O.S. allow the phanton process to access the file.

Comment: yes full path, also with file:///C:/path/file.txt  - same result

Comment: please post your code with sample files included..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a local disk file with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582671/how-to-open-a-local-disk-file-with-javascript)

Comment: I do feel rather silly now. The code I posted actually do work. For some reason an extra extension had been added to my local file, which I failed to realize. So rather than urls.txt, the file was named urls.txt.txt. Thanks for your time all the same